# Checkstyle plugin/tool which forces to fulfill before commit

Tags: git, development-environment, checkstyle, pre-commit-hook

I am looking for a checkstyle tool/plugin which doesn't allow you to commit unless everything fits the style.

Does anyone know anything?

Comment: which version control system?

Comment: Git, I have discovered the hooks can be set on pre-commit, I am investigating how to set checkstyle there.

Comment: Googling gave me [this](https://gist.github.com/davetron5000/37350), which looks promising.

Comment: Yes I am trying make it work! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1005481/thomas-jensen) mentioned, this [pre-commit hook](https://gist.github.com/davetron5000/37350) allows to trigger the checkstyle before commit.

It is quite easy to use, setup your checkstyle jar, path to java exec and specify the checks.